# zxing android embedded change the view

Tags: android, view, embed, zxing

my my question is :
how can i change che CompoundBarcodeView?
this is my screen : 
[mobile screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bjen3.jpg)
I want to remove the square viewfinder , the red bar and the text.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private TextView textView;
private SurfaceView surfaceView;

private static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;

private BarcodeCallback callback = new BarcodeCallback() {
    @Override
    public void barcodeResult(BarcodeResult result) {
        if (result.getText() != null) {
            textView.setText(result.getText());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void possibleResultPoints(List<ResultPoint> resultPoints) {
    }
};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.code_info);

    barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
    barcodeView.decodeContinuous(callback);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    barcodeView.resume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();

    barcodeView.pause();
}

public void pause(View view) {
    barcodeView.pause();
}

public void resume(View view) {
    barcodeView.resume();
}

public void triggerScan(View view) {
    barcodeView.decodeSingle(callback);
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return barcodeView.onKeyDown(keyCode, event) || super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

}
```

I am following [this](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/sample/src/main/java/example/zxing/ContinuousCaptureActivity.java) tutorial;
sorry for bad english, i'm italian.

Comment: This is The official [ZXing](https://github.com/zxing/zxing) project home.
Check it!

Comment: I've already seen it but I do not understand how to do

Comment: @alex , have you find the solution. If found then please share :)

Answer (score 0):

All you need is to change **CompoundBarcodeView** to **BarcodeView**

Remember to make changes in your layout xml also.

```
    <com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView
        ...>
    </com.journeyapps.barcodescanner.BarcodeView>
```

In your program:
change:

```
    private CompoundBarcodeView barcodeView;
    ...
    barcodeView = (CompoundBarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
```

to:

```
    private BarcodeView barcodeView;
    ...
    barcodeView = (BarcodeView) findViewById(R.id.camera_view);
```